# Wix Installer conditional code at run time

Tags: wix

In a Wix Installer, I have a checkbox on a custom screen.
I have to invoke a DoAction code when a check box is checked and another DoAction when it is unchecked.

All the searches on Stack Overflow are referring to build time conditional code. But I want it for runtime when Wix Installer is running and the user checks the checkbox. Also I don't want it inside the Custom Action dll.

e.g code.

```
if (Checkbox is checked)
{
    Set property GLOBALAUTHOR = property LOCALAUTHOR
    set property phonenumber to ""
}
else
{
    Set property GLOBALAUTHOR = ""
}
```

Any pointers will help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are an associated property and a value when checked (customizable) and a value when not checked (null)

You don't need a DoAction for what you show here.  Just use a series of mutually exclusive events.

SetProperty GLOBALAUTHOR = [LOCALAUTHOR] condition  CHECKBOXPROPERTY

SetProperty PHONENUMBER {}  condition CHECKBOXPROPERTY

SetProperty GLOBALAUTHOR = {} condition Not CHECKBOXPROPERTY

{} means to set the property to an null value.